# the code needed to save data in a JSON file, i.e. writing to it and adding it

Tags: json, flutter

All I want is the code needed to save data in a JSON file, i.e. writing to it and adding it, not reading it. I succeeded in that.
Also, I would like to inquire whether the data can be added instantaneously and immediately at the time of the actual operation of the application, or only when the application is closed?

Are there several ways to connect to JSON files, or is there only one way like this?!!
await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();

Finally, I will put the full code for you and show you the error messages
The first error message appears when the upload data button is pressed
`Error loading users: Expected a value of type 'List<dynamic>', but got one of type '_JsonMap'`

The second error message appears when trying to save data:
`Error saving users: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)`

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      home: HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<User> _users = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _loadUsers();
  }

// TO load data from site.json file.
  Future<void> _loadUsers() async {
    try {
      final jsonString = await rootBundle.loadString('assets/site.json');
      final List<dynamic> jsonList =json.decode(jsonString) as List;
      setState(() {
        _users = jsonList.map((json) => User.fromJson(json)).toList();
      
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error loading users: ${e.toString()}');
    }
  }
 
 // TO save data when add new data to site.json file.
  Future<void> _saveUsers() async {
    try {
      final jsonString = json.encode(_users);
      final file = await _getLocalFile();
      await file.writeAsString(jsonString);
      print('Users saved successfully');
    } catch (e) {
      print('Error saving users: ${e.toString()}');
    }
  }

  Future<File> _getLocalFile() async {
    final directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    return File('${directory.path}assets/site.json');
  }

  void _addUser() {
    setState(() {
      _users.add(User(name: 'John', age: 30));
    });
  }

  void _clearUsers() {
    setState(() {
      _users.clear();
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Flutter Demo'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
           ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _loadUsers,
              child: Text('Load Users'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _saveUsers,
              child: Text('Save Users'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _addUser,
              child: Text('Add User'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _clearUsers,
              child: Text('Clear Users'),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 20),
            Text('Users:'),
            Expanded(
              child: ListView.builder(
                itemCount: _users.length,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                  final user = _users[index];
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(user.name),
                    subtitle: Text('${user.age} years old'),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class User {
  final String name;
  final int age;

  User({required this.name, required this.age});

  factory User.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      User(name: json['name'], age: json['age']);

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {'name': name, 'age': age};
}
```

Answer (score 0):

before assigning the json.decode to a variable type, you can print the runtimeType and the list itseft,

```
 //DONT DO: final List<dynamic> jsonList =json.decode(jsonString) as List;

 //DO: final dynamic jsonData = json.decode(jsonString);
 log(jsonData.runtimeType)
 log(jsonData)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help John, but I keep getting the error messages!! like this one                                     
Error loading users: Expected a value of type '(String, dynamic) => MapEntry<dynamic, dynamic>', but got one of type '(dynamic) => User'

Comment: and this    Error saving users: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the code that allows me to write to the JSON file

Comment: well need to see the json file itself to see where the root problem is

Comment: yes , the path is (assets/site.json)

Comment: { 
    "user" :[
    {
        "name":"sife",
        "age":44
    },
    {
        "name":"hasan",
        "age":22
    }
]
}

Comment: When I learned that no file could be modified inside the assets folder, I did the following:
1- Trying to use a variable in some way to store data inside it, but how to call it again, I didn't succeed.
2- Using SQLite also shows the same problem and error messages
3 - Trying to store the data and call it from a text file, but it is also useless

Comment: * Sometimes the application hangs during the build phase at this line in the terminal
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1
* And often when using () whether to use it with a json file or with sqlite, the following code appears:
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method getApplicationDocumentsDirectory on channel plugins.flutter.io/path_provider)
* When trying to store data or read it from an external text file, the following message appears:
Unsupported operation: _Namespace

Comment: In short, all my attempts to just store and add data to a json file or to a sqlite database file or even a text file